# Using ruby send method to create and build a new class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some classes that I want to call dynamiclly:

```rb
 Sms::Message::TenMinutesBeforeReminderMessage.new(data).build
```

```rb
Sms::Message::OneHourAfterReminderMessage.new(data).build
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```rb
send("Sms::Message::#{reminder}ReminderMessage.new(data).build")
```

Where `reminder` is a symbol. 
Is this possible? If so I can't seem to figure out the syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [constantize](https://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize) from Rails to do it:

```
klass = "Sms::Message::#{reminder}ReminderMessage".constantize
klass.new(data).build
```